# Adding the first description to a set of unique values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that looks a little something like this -
[image: Unique Code Example]

It uses this code when a button is pressed to provide me the unique values in Column C from the concatenation of column A and B

```
   Dim Ary As Variant
   Dim r As Long
   
   Ary = Range("A2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
   
   With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
      For r = 1 To UBound(Ary)
         .Item(Ary(r, 1) & " " & Ary(r, 2)) = Empty
      Next r
      Range("C2").Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
   End With
End Sub
```

I am looking to modify my spreadsheet so it looks like this instead - [image: Unique Code with Description Example]

I have been trying to figure out how to get the first description line in column C to be placed in column E in line with its unique value. Output would look something like this - [image: Unique Code with Unique Description Example]

This way even though some of these codes have multiple unique descriptions only the first description is placed in column E. Any suggestions on how to tackle this would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be VBA? Should be doable with a formula.

Comment: I mean, it doesn't really have to... but I'd like to learn to do it as I'm just trying to find ways to update it to work with VBA whilst I learn VBA as I had a spreadsheet before with formulas that was very slow but didn't include the descriptions.

Comment: You could assign the description to the dictionary item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some small adjustments really:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant, lr As Long, x As Long
   
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
arr = Range("A2:C" & lr).Value
   
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If .Exists(arr(x, 1) & " " & arr(x, 2)) Then
            'We don't want to overwrite in this case!
        Else
            .Item(arr(x, 1) & " " & arr(x, 2)) = arr(x, 3)
        End If
    Next
    Range("D2").Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
    Range("E2").Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Items)
End With

End Sub
```

Note that you are still using implicit sheet references like this, meaning you are always supposed to work from the then active worksheet.